# Tile problem when browser is zoomed in

Tags: openlayers, mapserver, mapcache, ms4w

I'm using mapcache/mapserver/openlayers 3 with ms4w. When my application is loaded with the browser at the normal 100% zoom level, everything returns fine (testing on chrome, firefox, and edge). The map requests are:

```
mymapcacheserver?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=newlayer&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&BBOX=33.75%2C-94.21875%2C35.15625%2C-92.8125
```

However, some of my users are using the zoom feature of the browser and zooming in to levels above 100% and that changes the height and width values. At 150%, it sets the height and width to 384 and adds MAP_RESOLUTION=135 to the URL.

```
mymapcacheserver?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=newlayer&WIDTH=384&HEIGHT=384&CRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&MAP_RESOLUTION=135&BBOX=33.75%2C-94.21875%2C35.15625%2C-92.8125
```

When this happens, only a handful of tiles are returned and mapcache/wms server won't respond to any future web requests. I can pan or zoom over the map, but all generated requests are never fulfilled.

I can change the height and width of the requests in a new/reloaded tab and it returns the appropriate tiles immediately.

A previous version of my application that was using older versions of mapcache/mapserver/openlayers did not have this problem. Other than the version differences, I am now using the predefined grids in mapcache, instead of defining my own.

If I point my layers directly at mapserver, instead of using mapcache, the tiles returned from mapserver work as expected with the updated height/width/map_resolution values.

Can anyone point me to where I need to look to resolve this issue? This is a sanitized version of my mapfile.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mapcache>

   <grid name="WGS84">
      <metadata>
         <title>GoogleCRS84Quad</title>
         <WellKnownScaleSet>urn:ogc:def:wkss:OGC:1.0:GoogleCRS84Quad</WellKnownScaleSet>
      </metadata>
      <extent>-180 -90 180 90</extent>
      <srs>EPSG:4326</srs>
      <units>dd</units>
      <size>256 256</size>
      <resolutions>0.703125000000000 0.351562500000000 0.175781250000000 8.78906250000000e-2 4.39453125000000e-2 2.19726562500000e-2 1.09863281250000e-2 5.49316406250000e-3 2.74658203125000e-3 1.37329101562500e-3 6.86645507812500e-4 3.43322753906250e-4 1.71661376953125e-4 8.58306884765625e-5 4.29153442382812e-5 2.14576721191406e-5 1.07288360595703e-5 5.36441802978516e-6</resolutions>
   </grid>   

   <cache name="disk" type="disk">
      <base>E:/mapcache/disk</base>
      <!--<symlink_blank/>-->
   </cache>  

   <cache name="sqlitecache" type="sqlite3">
      <dbfile>E:/mapcache/sqlite/{tileset}.db</dbfile>
      <pragma name="max_page_count">10000000</pragma>
   </cache>   

   <source name="statemap" type="wms">
      <http>
         <url>http://mymapserverurl/fcgi-bin/mapserv.exe?map=/path/to/my/mapfile.map</url>
          </http>      
      <getmap>
         <params>
            <MAP>d:/path/to/my/mapfile.map</MAP>
            <FORMAT>image/png</FORMAT>
            <LAYERS>statemap</LAYERS>
         </params>
      </getmap>
   </source>

   <!-- Tilesets -->
   <!-- Tilesets name must match layer name both from wms & source -->       

   <tileset name="statemap">
      <title>Statemap</title>
      <source>statemap</source>
      <cache>sqlitecache</cache>   
      <grid use_wms_intermediate_resolutions="true">WGS84</grid>
      <grid>g</grid>
      <format>PNG</format>
      <metatile>5 5</metatile>
      <metabuffer>10</metabuffer>
      <expires>2592000</expires>
   </tileset>   

   <!-- settings -->

   <default_format>JPEG</default_format>

   <format name="PNG_FAST" type="PNG">
      <compression>fast</compression>
      <colors>256</colors>
   </format>

   <format name="PNG_BEST" type="PNG">
      <compression>best</compression>
   </format>  

   <format name="MIXED" type="MIXED">
      <transparent>PNG_BEST</transparent>
      <opaque>JPEG</opaque>
   </format>      

   <service type="wms" enabled="true">
      <full_wms>assemble</full_wms>
      <resample_mode>bilinear</resample_mode>
      <format>PNG</format>

   </service>
   <service type="wmts" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="tms" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="kml" enabled="true"/>
   <service type="gmaps" enabled="false"/>
   <service type="ve" enabled="false"/>
   <service type="demo" enabled="false"/>

   <threaded_fetching>true</threaded_fetching>

   <errors>report</errors>
   <lock_dir>E:/mapcache/locks</lock_dir>

</mapcache>
```